# How to replace one word in a text file (0000000:theword)

Tags: python

I have been trying to replace a word in a text file that has numbers and names separated by a colon.

```
@@000000000000000:name1@@00000000000000:name2@@
```

Each `number:name` combination is wrapped with a pair of `@` characters.

I am trying to replace the name with the new name if the number already exists in the file.

```
with open('file.txt','r+') as f:
  for line in f:
    if number in line and number not in line:
       ## I tried for many hours here and couldn't get it to work.
       ## found a few things online but still.
       ## I feel like I need to find either the the specific number:name
       ## combination first and then replace only the number.
```

Comment: `number in line and number not in line` will evaluate to `False` every time

Comment: A regex with a couple capture groups might help `'@(\d+)\:([^@]+)@'` where the first capture group would be the number and the second would be the name. Then you can put them in a dict or something, then check for uniqueness before writing back to file.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input, and the output you would expect? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using split() to parse through your file:

```
new_name = 'foo'
existing_num = [#list of existing]

with open('some_file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        pairs = line.rstrip().split('@@')
        for pair in pairs:
            if pair.split(':')[0] in existing_num:
                pair.split(':')[1] == new_name
        new_line = "@@{}@@".format(("@@").join(pairs))
        # write new line in place of old one if editing in place
```